# Is there a version of Rapids for ARM64 architecture?

Tags: arm64

Is there a version of Rapids or a Docker image for ARM64 architecture, specifically am trying to run on nVidia Jetson Xavier?

Comment: Which "Rapids" product or tool are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is out of the box: CUDA, yes; Rapids and Dask, no.

However, there is [a GitHub project you may be interested in](https://github.com/awthomp/rapids-jetson).